# How to use drupal_add_library with a module?

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm new to Drupal and don't really understand how to set up [drupal_add_library](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_library/7.x).

I've made a simple module that links out to a .js file. However, this .js file depends on a couple of generic functions. I've put this generic functions in a library and want to call them.

I've set up my code as such:

```
function products_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  drupal_add_library($module, $name);
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'products') . '/assets/myScript.js');
}
```

But am not sure what to put in $module and $name (I'm assuming name is the actual name of the .js you want to call from the library), or even if this is the right place to call it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I need to register the library with [hook_library](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_library/7.x) first.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it in that hook if you want it on every page (or add some logic to restrict the pages that it loads on), that's fine.

As per the [API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_library/7.x):

> **$module:** The name of the module that registered the library.
>
> **$name:** The name of the library to add.

If you're creating your own library, Jimmy Ko is correct: you need to declare it in hook_library.

Note that `$name` should exclude the file extension (e.g. `.js`)

Answer (score 0):

The arguments required by [`drupal_add_library()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_library/7.x) are the following.

- `$module`: The machine name of the module that registered the library in a `hook_library()` implementation
- $name: The name of the library to add

For example, for the *farbtastic* library, the call to `drupal_add_library()` should be `drupal_add_library('system', 'farbastic')`, since that library is defined in [`system_library()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_library/7.x).

Adding libraries and JavaScript in `hook_preprocess_page()` is probably too late, as  [`template_process_html()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_process_html/7.x) already added them to the page markup.

```php
  $variables['head'] = drupal_get_html_head();
  $variables['css'] = drupal_add_css();
  $variables['styles'] = drupal_get_css();
  $variables['scripts'] = drupal_get_js();
```

It's preferable to use [`hook_page_build()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_page_build/7.x) to add the library (and the JavaScript code) using the *#attached* property as described in [How to add jQuery UI libraries to a page](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/howtos/how-to-add-jquery-ui-libraries-to-a-page). (Despite the title, what described is valid for every library and JavaScript code.)

Since *#attached* can be used in any render array or form array, it can be used in any hook that returns a render or a form array, or that alters a render or a form array, including `hook_form_alter()`.

```php
  // Adds a form field that the javascript utilizes or modifies.
  $form['location'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Your Location (Country)',
    '#id' => 'country_autocomplete',
    // Both the library and custom JavaScript code are added to the '#attached'
    // property of a renderable array.
    '#attached' => array(
      'library' => array(
        array('system', 'ui.autocomplete'),
      ),
      'js' => array(
        "$path/mymodule-custom-javascript.js",
      ),
    ),
  ); 
}
```

Drupal can use only the libraries that are added with [`hook_library()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_library/7.x), which means that a module that wants to use its own libraries needs to `hook_library()` too.

You can also add a `scripts[]` line in the module/theme .info file if that JavaScript code needs to be added to every page, as described in [Writing module .info files (Drupal 7.x)](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/writing-module-info-files-drupal-7x). This allows JavaScript to be aggregated in an optimal way.
CSS styles can also be added with `stylesheets[]`.

```
stylesheets[all][] = node.css
scripts[] = somescript.js
```